# IIS: 405 (Method not allowed) when posting to default page

Tags: iis, post, http-status-code-405

i want to `POST` form data to the default page of a web-server, e.g.:

```
POST http://errorreporting.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

i want the server to be responsible for `302` redirecting the client to where the `POST` should go. The `default.asp` file on the server performs this task ([which is the technique Microsoft recommends](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216493)), by performing the `Redirect`:

**default.asp:**

```
<%
   Response.Redirect "SubmitError.ashx"
%>
```

When i simply **browse** the server:

```
GET http://errorreporting.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

i get the expected response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Location: SubmitError.ashx
...
```

But when i `POST` to the server:

```
POST http://errorreporting.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

The server gets very grumpy with me:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed
Connection: close
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD
...
```

i want the **server** to be able to redirect the **client** to the appropriate submit `URL`, rather than hard-coding the client with the **URL**. This is, of course, because the URL could (i.e. has) changed:

- `http://errorreporting.example.com/SubmitError.asp`
- `http://errorreporting.example.com/SubmitError.aspx`
- `http://errorreporting.example.com/SubmitError.ashx`
- `http://errorreporting.example.com/ErrorReporting/Submit.ashx`
- `http://errorreporting.example.com/submiterror.php`
- `http://errorreporting.example.com/submit/submiterror.ashx`

etc.

**Note**: If i change the `URL` to include the document location:

```
/* SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://www.example.com:8088/ErrorReporting/SubmitError.ashx';
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://www.example.com/ErrorReporting/SubmitError.ashx';
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://errorreporting.example.com:8088/ErrorReporting/SubmitError.ashx';
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://errorreporting.example.com/SubmitError.ashx';
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://errorreporting.example.com';
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://errorreporting.example.com/SubmitError.ashx'; 
*/
   SErrorReportingUrl = 'http://errorreporting.example.com/submit/SubmitError.ashx';
```

It works fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out getting IIS to support `POST` doesn't really help.

i'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to perform the `POST`s. Nearly every implementation of `XMLHttpRequest` out there (*e.g.* Chrome, Internet Explorer, MSXML) has a bug where it performs a `GET`, instead of a `POST`, after following the redirect.

The [W3C's XMLHttpReqest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) says that redirects should be followed and requests reissued:

> If the response is an HTTP redirect:
>
> If the redirect does not violate security
>   (it is [same origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin) for instance),
>   infinite loop precautions, and the
>   scheme is supported, transparently
>   follow the redirect while observing
>   the [same-origin request event rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin-request-event-rules).
>
> *Note: HTTP places requirements on the user
>   agent regarding the preservation of
>   the [**request method**](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#request-method) and [**request entity
>   body**](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#request-entity-body) during redirects, and also
>   requires end users to be notified of
>   certain kinds of automatic
>   redirections.*

And [here's a site](http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/) where you can test the bug in your browser's `XmlHttpRequest` implementation.

---

In the end, i'll work around an **IIS** bug, and an `XMLHttpRequest` bug, by having my "default" page do everything that a `302 redirect` would, but return `200 OK` instead:

> `HTTP/1.1`**`200 OK`**
>   `Connection: close`
>   `Date: Sun, 27 Jun 2010 13:28:14 GMT`
>   `Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0`
>   **`Location: http://errorreporting.example.com/submit/SubmitError.ashx`**
>   `Content-Length: 92`
>   `Content-Type: text/html`
>   `Cache-control: private`
>
> ```
> <HTML><BODY>This content has moved <A href="submit/SubmitError.ashx">here.</A></BODY></HTML>
> ```

i'm forcing the client to do two hits anyway - might as well have it work right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Vue.js on Express/Node.  The back-end is running on server port 3300, but we didn't want to expose that publicly.

I installed the requirements ([Application Request Writing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) and [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)) and then added an Inbound Rule to rewrite the back-end requests to Express, but I kept getting 405 (Method not allowed).

Eventually I got it going by gleaning a few ideas from [Stefano Scerra's Blog](https://www.stefanoscerra.it/iis-rewrite-rules-configuration-angular-web-config/).

Here's my final web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="api" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^api/(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.1.1.217:3300/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Filter" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="100-999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```